# Correct definition of a function that takes callable as its input

Tags: c++, c++14, type-traits, callable

Is it correct to define a function `foo` that takes as its input a callable as follows:

```
template< typename callable_t >
void foo( callable_t f )
{
  // code that calls f 
}
```

Do we need any type traits to ensure that `f` is a callable? I would say "no" since the compiler will throw an error in case that I pass, for example, an `int` to `foo` and try to call it.

What do you think?

Comment: You can enforce it with SFINAE come c++17, which brings [`std::is_callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable). You should also consider the fact member functions need special care (again solved in c++17 with [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)), and that passing by value may be expansive or even impossible for some functors.

Comment: I am using C++14? How should `foo` be programmed in C++14?

Comment: A possible implementation of `std::invoke` can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke). You can place it into it's own namespace ant use it conditionally on the current standard version (which is given to the preprocessor in the standard [macro __cplusplus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace)).